# Why am I receiving twice the query params in React?

Tags: reactjs, parameters

I'm trying to receive a param value in the Parent Component (Home) and send it directly to my child Component (Cars). But, before sending it I've checked using console.log to see which params were being sent and somewhat it was sending two params instead of just one. Why is that happening?

Here is my code:

```
function Home(props) {

const [query, setQuery] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    async function wait() {
        await setQuery(props.match.params.id);  
    } 
    wait();
    console.log(query);
});

return (
    <Fragment>
        <Header />
        <Cars />
    </Fragment>
)}
```

For example, when I click on the child component it should go to directly to: "http://localhost:3000/marca/1". And I should receive on the console.log: 1.
Instead I gotta: "undefined" and "0"

Comment: What happens if you give your effect a dependency array?  I also don't understand why you are using an `async/await`.  `setQuery` is synchronous.  What do you **think** is happening?

Comment: You get `undefined` first since the log method runs before the `async` function has resolved, when the `async` function completes, state updates and causes a re-render which runs the `useEffect` hook again and the second log method, with the defined value. Why that value is defined `0` instead of `1` I can't say, I have no knowledge of what prop data is being passed down, but it may be that your index is actually beginning at `0` and not `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 2 logs because of your component is updated 2 times:
1) during mounting (with `query = undefined`)
2) after calling `setQuery`, hence `query` became updated

If you want to call `useEffect` only once, just pass an `[]` as second argument to `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function wait() {
        await setQuery(props.match.params.id);  
    } 
    wait();
    console.log(query);
}, []);
```

If you need to trigger `useEffect` every time query updates, just pass an array of all values which `useEffect` is used:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function wait() {
        await setQuery(props.match.params.id);  
    } 
    wait();
    console.log(query);
}, [query, setQuery]);
```

More information you can get there: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html